# App Engine SearchAPI: java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: Task was cancelled

Tags: java, google-app-engine, full-text-search

Some of my App Engine Search API queries give a 'java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: Task was cancelled' exception. The error is reproducable.

I have multiple indexes. On some indexes, those queries run, on others they fail.
The query is very basic. If I run it from the admin console (https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/search/index), it gives no problem.
There is nothing special about the query.

The query filters on 2 atom fields: isReliable = "1" AND markedForDelete = "0", and sorts on a number field.

There seems nothing wrong with the code, as it runs many of such queries with no problem, far more difficult as the failing ones.

Comment: I've seen such exceptions caused by timeout limits. Check in the logs if you get them after app. the same execution time (e.g. 59-60 seconds).

Comment: That is indeed the problem. So the problem is why does it take so long. Running it in the admin console, the query takes 25 seconds. I think the slowness is related to the fact that the sort criterion has too many equal values, which is not recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen such exceptions caused by timeout limits. Check in the logs if you get them after app. the same execution time (e.g. 59-60 seconds).

If this is not a user-facing request, you can move it into a task, which has 10 minutes execution limit. If this is a user-facing request, some changes in the data model might be necessary. For example, you may combine some fields into flags  for frequently used queries, e.g. isReliable = "1" AND markedForDelete = "0" becomes code = "10" or "reliableToDelete = "true".

Comment: pls take a look at my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38716279/app-engine-modules-not-working