# App engine PHP modules not working

Tags: php, python, google-app-engine

I read the docs about GAE's modules. This [sample application](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-modules-helloworld-python) shows how to use modules in a GAE app. I have modified the code little bit to use both [php and python languages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21588987/3297613) on that.

Here is the [Github link](https://github.com/Avinash-Raj/appengine-modules-helloworld-python) where the corresponding code resides.

When I try to run this application on my local machine, by running this command

```
dev_appserver.py dispatch.yaml app.yaml php.yaml static_backend.yaml --php_executable_path /usr/bin/php
```

all works fine except the code written in php. When I try to access that particular part by triggering this `localhost:8080/mobile/`, I get an empty page instead of `Hello World`.

Comment: what do you see on the logs?

Comment: On logs it won't show any error just GET /mobile/ 200

Comment: could you please add your complete log since running the `dev_appserver.py` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have ran your code without a problem.

[image: php module]
[image: python module]

```
dev_appserver.py dispatch.yaml app.yaml php.yaml static_backend.yaml 
INFO     2016-08-03 04:19:01,413 devappserver2.py:769] Skipping SDK update check.
INFO     2016-08-03 04:19:01,517 api_server.py:205] Starting API server at: http://localhost:52017
INFO     2016-08-03 04:19:01,520 dispatcher.py:185] Starting dispatcher running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2016-08-03 04:19:01,526 dispatcher.py:197] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8081
INFO     2016-08-03 04:19:01,718 dispatcher.py:197] Starting module "php-module" running at: http://localhost:8082
INFO     2016-08-03 04:19:01,734 dispatcher.py:197] Starting module "static-backend" running at: http://localhost:8083
INFO     2016-08-03 04:19:01,744 admin_server.py:116] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
INFO     2016-08-03 04:19:02,209 module.py:1730] New instance for module "php-module" serving on:
http://localhost:8082

INFO     2016-08-03 04:19:02,759 module.py:1730] New instance for module "static-backend" serving on:
http://localhost:8083

INFO     2016-08-03 04:19:03,283 module.py:788] php-module: "GET /_ah/start HTTP/1.1" 200 24
INFO     2016-08-03 04:19:03,470 module.py:788] static-backend: "GET /_ah/start HTTP/1.1" 200 3108
INFO     2016-08-03 04:19:15,683 module.py:788] static-backend: "GET /mobile/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3752
INFO     2016-08-03 04:19:16,407 module.py:788] static-backend: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 3626
INFO     2016-08-03 04:19:18,914 module.py:788] static-backend: "GET /mobile HTTP/1.1" 200 3710
INFO     2016-08-03 04:19:19,345 module.py:788] static-backend: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 3650
INFO     2016-08-03 04:19:21,096 module.py:788] static-backend: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3648
```

Try the following:

- Installing all necessary PHP extensions using `gcloud components install app-engine-php`
- Omitting the `--php-executable-flag`
- Making sure it is correct with the command `which php` on your terminal, and pointing the `--php-executable-flag` to your `php-cgi`

Comment: what error do you see and what does `which php` show you?

Comment: I got it working by running `dev_appserver.py dispatch.yaml app.yaml php.yaml static_backend.yaml --php_executable_path /usr/bin/php-cgi` command. ie, we have to mention the php-cgi path